# AngularJS Module 'agGrid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

This is common problem and Googling shows lots of instances of it, many of them on this site.

The answers seem to boil down to :

- not injecting the module into the app
- for getting to include the relevant JS
- including things in the wrong order in `index.html`

I am trying to include ag-grid, following the [instructions for manual include](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/#gsc.tab=0).

In my `index.html`, I include

1. Angular
2. ag-grid
3. my controller

I am using the [Inspinia](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/inspinia-responsive-admin-theme-WB0R5L90S) template, and the relevant code is

```
(function () {
    angular.module('TapThatDashboard', 
    [
        'ui.router',                    // Routing
        'oc.lazyLoad',                  // ocLazyLoad
        'ui.bootstrap',                 // Ui Bootstrap
        'chart.js',                     // Charting
        'agGrid'
    ])
})();
```

Note that the other stuff is working, such as the charting.

When I remove the `'agGrid'` line, my app runs just fine (I have not yet added any grid to my HTML). When I add it in, I get

> Module 'agGrid' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it

My code is far too large to post. Can anyone see what I am doing wrongly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your code like

```
// if you're using ag-Grid-Enterprise, you'll need to provide the License Key before doing anything else
// not necessary if you're just using ag-Grid
agGrid.LicenseManager.setLicenseKey("your license key goes here");

// get ag-Grid to create an Angular module and register the ag-Grid directive
agGrid.initialiseAgGridWithAngular1(angular);

// create your module with ag-Grid as a dependency
var module = angular.module("example", ["agGrid"]);
```

Reference Link : [agGrid](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angularjs-data-grid/#gsc.tab=0)

Comment: D'oh! I read that - but did not see it :-/  Thanks for being my eyes. No errors now. Next step is adding a grid to my code.